# Uploading CSV file in Rest Assured returns 500

Tags: multipartform-data, rest-assured, multipart

I've been struggling to upload my CSV file via Rest Assured. It returns 500, while it works fine on Postman.

```
File myFile = new File("src\test\resources\myfile.csv");

    response = given()
            .spec(requestSpecification).config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
            .multiPart("file", myFile,"multipart/form-data")
            .when()
            .post(endpoint)
            .then().extract().response();
```

I also tried

- without: `encoderConfig & appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined`
- with:

  ```
        .body(file)
        .contentType("text/csv")
  ```

also,

```
.config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.MULTIPART)))
                .contentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=--MyBoundary")
```

I think I've tried everything I found on the internet, but it still returns 500.

[image]

[image]

On Postman it works fine
I focused mainly of multipart/contentType part, but maybe the issue lies somewhere else?

[image]

Do you have any others ideas? I'd be very grateful

EDIT:
POSTMAN console

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you screenshot the request + header in postman console?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 I updated main post. I see there's a boundary calculated in Postman, but I also tried with this:  `.contentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=--MyBoundary")` and same result:

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 still same issue. It must be something with the boundary I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose this method `multiPart(String controlName, File file, String mimeType)` to upload, then the last parameter is mimeType "text/csv"

```java
.multiPart("file", myFile, "text/csv");
```

full code:

```java
File myFile = new File("src\\test\\resources\\myfile.csv");

response = given()
    .spec(requestSpecification)
    .multiPart("file", myFile, "text/csv")
    .when()
    .post(endpoint)
    .then().extract().response();
```

Comment: Didn't work, still 500 :(

Comment: Did the response contain anything helpful?

Comment: no, internal server error. But have you checked my edited post about boundaries info?

Comment: yes I did but boundaries info is generated by postman, doesn't affect server. Error 500 means server doesn't understand the data in the request, it doesn't know how to deal with that, for example, it expects a content-type: json but request said it's xml. To solve this, best way is to check the server side code and log to see what error is.

Comment: it worked with double backslashes! Thank you